# Make formula impossible to find / read

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, privacy

I have developed a spreadsheet for performing various calculations which our employees will complete and then distribute to clients / competitors. To protect the "intellectual property" of the spreadsheet I want to make it completely impossible for the recipient to be able to view the calculations used to return the results.

All the calculations / formula are on a separate sheet to the "body" of the form.

Considerations I have made with their downfalls include;

Setting the `Visible` property within the VBA editor to `2 - xlSheetVeryHidden` but anyone with anything about them could easily bypass this.

Password protecting the workbook / sheet - again, a quick Google turns up some very simple [workarounds](https://uknowit.uwgb.edu/page.php?id=28850) (tried, tested and verified).

Writing a VBA script to destroy any calculations / formula on the `Worksheet_Activate()` sub but simply disallowing macros when the file opens gets around this.

I even considered writing some VBA to BUILD the calculations sheet when the file opens to force the user to have macros enabled, meaning they could be destroyed if they tried to access them; however this would not only be a huge task in itself, but someone with enough time could just pull all the data from the "build" sub of the VBA code.

Even while writing this I'm rapidly losing but hope there may be a method unbeknown to me which someone on this community has stumbled across / had to implement themselves.

*Note; the file DOES have to be distributed to clients in Excel format, cannot be PDF'd etc.*

Comment: Have you considered trying to obfuscate the code? It wan't be impossible to decrypt but would be very difficult; that is, if obfuscation is possible in this case.

Comment: Do the recipients need to get spreadsheets with proprietary formulas or are the formulas only to process the employee input and could be replaced with resultant values before distribution?

Comment: fixer1234: The formula could be replaced by resultant values before distribution but there is a chance amendments may need to be made which would involve reverting the resultant values back to their original state.

Comment: techaddict: This seems like a possibility, however having done 5 mins research (had never heard of it before your comment!) would this mean I need to build all the formula using VBA? Currently all calcs are just done on a sheet in cells, not in VBA

Comment: The answer below by @teylyn is the correct answer, this isn't a safe way to do things. Have you considered doing the calculations and putting a macro in that will run and extract the values/results into a new workbook that doesn't include the formulas, which then can be sent freely?

Comment: re: amendments vs. replacing with resultant values--keep the original version in case amendments are needed.  Make the changes, replace the formulas with resultant values, and resend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to completely protect an Excel file. Excel sheet protection and even VBA code protection should be regarded as a safeguard against accidental change rather than malicious intent. The internet is full of free and paid tools to support malicious intent.

The only way to keep an Excel file safe is not to make it available to others who might hack into it.